# Gradle plugin to read secret (api-key, password) properties (like buildConfigField from Android plugin)

Tags: java, build.gradle, password-protection, secret-key, android-buildconfig

**Is there any gradle function/plugin to read/bind some secret properties (api keys, passwords) from special config/properties files?**

[For instance, in android plugin](http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/28/customizing-your-build-with-gradle/) you can set properties in *~/.gradle/gradle.properties* file:

`apiKey=SUPER_SECRET_VALUE`

than in project *build.gradle*:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", apiKey
        }
    }    
}
```

And in project itself you use `BuildConfig.API_KEY` string constant.

Is there any similar solutions in gradle for other (java) projects?

Or may be this approach is wrong and some other workaround should be used?

Answer (score 1):

You can always [filter files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files). You pass resources or source files through a copy command and replace tokens like `@API_KEY@` (with `filter` and `ReplaceTokens`) or `${API_KEY}` (using `expand`) with Gradle variables.

For example:

```
processResources {
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [API_KEY: apiKey])
}
```

Would replace the substring `@API_KEY@` with your actual API key in any of your resource files.

Comment: it looks like old-school Ant-Maven solution, but i'm looking for something modern and actual

Comment: What specifically don't you like about this solution other than you think it's old-school? Android's doing roughly the same thing for you. The only real difference is it seems Android's generating source code, while `filter` is only modifying resources. You could even use this technique to replace values in Java files.

Comment: In this solution i don't like exactly this: "Android's generating source code, while filter is only modifying resources" :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to my prior answer, you can write a custom Gradle task that uses [CodeModel](https://codemodel.java.net). [Here](http://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/android/how-to-generate-java-sources-using-buildsrc-gradle-project/)'s an example.